# How to write sum(if a>=10 and a<=100,a,0) like SQL in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to make the same SQL statement as specified `select sum(if a >= 10 and a <= 100, a, 0) from table` in `MongoDb`.

Therefore, I write:

```
{
    "$project": {
        "sumqty": {
            "a1": {
                "$cond": {
                    "if": {
                        "$and": [{"$gte":["$a",10]},
                                 {"$lte":["$a",100]}]
                     },
                     "then": "$a",
                     "else": 0
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

```
db.table.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    totalSum: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: [{ $and: [{ $gte: ["$a", 10] }, { $lte: ["$a", 100] }] },
          "$a",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Instead of using `$cond`, you can also use two stages: `$match: {a: {$gte: 10, $lte:100}}` then `{$group: {$sum: '$a'}}`. The `$match` will filter the necessary documents, and the `$group` will sum them. This will have the benefit of using an index if such an index is defined on field `a`.

Comment: db.table.aggregate([{$match:{a:{'$gte':10,'$lte':100}}},{$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:'$a'}}}]) it will work too. I made Above query  explaining simplicity for  @ighack. Thanks

Comment: I know user $match,but if I want to select sum(if name='kk',a,0),sum(if name='yy',a,0) from table it doesn't works

Comment: select sum(if name='kk',a,0) as kkSum, sum(if name='yy', a, 0) as yySum from table then use it  in statge
{$group:{_id:null,kkSum:{$sum:{$cond:[{$and:[{$gte:["$a",10]},{$lte:["$a",100]},{$eq:["$name",'kk']}]},"$a",0]}},yySum:{$sum:{$cond:[{$and:[{$gte:["$a",10]},{$lte:["$a",100]},{$eq:["$name",'yy']}]},"$a",0]}}} lets have a look it. Thanks.